# Tuple index out of range python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
start = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
def print_board(turn, board):
    print(turn + " turn" + "\n   {}{}{}\n   {}{}{}\n   {}{}{}".format(board))
current_turn = "your"
print_board(current_turn, start)
```

The above stuff gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 5, in <module>
    print_board(current_turn, start)
  File "so.py", line 3, in print_board
    print(turn + " turn" + "\n   {}{}{}\n   {}{}{}\n   {}{}{}".format(x for x in board))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I've got 9 values in my tuple or list and  9 curly brackets. Right?

Comment: Can you clarify your code a bit? Maybe use the code block?

Comment: I want to make a very ugly and stupid tic tac toe program so I want to store the board ( idk how else to call that) in one list instead of 9 different variables

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 9):

The `format` method expects individual arguments rather than a single list.  But you can easily fix it by changing:

```
"...".format(board)
```

to:

```
"...".format(*board)
```

The asterisk `*` will cause the list elements to be passed as individual arguments.

Comment: that is handy to know

Answer (score 0):

You have only one item in the values list for the `print` -- a list.
You need to split out the individual integers.

```
def print_board(turn, board):
    print(turn + " turn" + "\n   {}{}{}\n   {}{}{}\n   {}{}{}".format(
        board[0], board[1], board[2],
        board[3], board[4], board[5],
        board[6], board[7], board[8]
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I split them out?

Comment: Thnx everyone! It worked with the "*" before the list

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 'format' works like that with lists. You would need something like this I believe.

```
x=[1,2]
print('one + {} = {}'.format(x[0],x[1]))
```